# reate an alert in Dynatrace for when the pod count of any workload within a specific namespace is zero,. So, Need some guidance on the query

Tags: alert, metrics, dynatrace

Create an alert in Dynatrace for when the pod count of any workload within a specific namespace is zero,. So, Need some guidance on the metric query

builtin:kubernetes.pods:filter(and(ne(pod_phase,Failed),ne(pod_phase,Succeeded),ne(k8s.workload.kind,job),ne(k8s.workload.kind,cronjob))):splitBy(k8s.namespace.name,k8s.workload.kind,k8s.workload.name):sum-builtin:kubernetes.pods:filter(and(ne(pod_phase,Failed),ne(pod_phase,Succeeded),ne(k8s.workload.kind,job),ne(k8s.workload.kind,cronjob),ne(pod_condition,Ready))):splitBy(k8s.namespace.name,k8s.workload.kind,k8s.workload.name):sum:default(0.0)